# how to set payment method selection required alert on checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, alert, required

> Is there any solution for this?
> Without selecting any payment method there is nothing showing alert or required warning, how can I set there?

[image]

Comment: Can you give url to website? Are you sure if you click place order and scroll up there is no message? Anyway you can start from checking what action is triggered by place order button and examine the path in javascript code. Then you will be able to see what and where you can change to improve UX in your checkout.

Comment: I have fixed it thank you for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have fixed this issue using jquery

```
$('body').on("touchstart click", '#place-order-trigger', function () {
    $('body').find('.paymentmode').remove();
    var paymethod = $("input[name='payment[method]']:checked").val();
    if(paymethod)
    {                           
        $(".payment-method._active").find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger( 'click' );
    }
    else
    {
        var mySecondDiv=$('<div  class="paymentmode alert alert-danger"><small>PLEASE SELECT PAYMENT METHOD.</small></div>');
        $('.payment-group .step-title').append(mySecondDiv);        
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.paymentmode').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 3000);
    }                                                                    
 });
```